# Getting additional fields in list operation for Google Drives API v3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to use the Google Drive API v3 to list out all the shared drives which the user has access to, along with some additional fields.

I've determined that I can use the fields optional parameter to list the fields I want, but am running into the situation where it does not seem to want to give me what I ask for.

The fields I'm specifically after are:

- ID
- Name
- Capabilities (to see if the user is able to write to the drive, etc)

All these examples below have been tried in the Google API explorer.

With no fields specified, I get the following. This is expected.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#driveList",
 "nextPageToken": "...",
 "drives": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "xxxx",
   "name": "Example Drive"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "xxxy",
   "name": "Another Example Drive"
  },
  // ...
```

With a fields value of `drives(id,name,capabilities)`, I get:

```
{
 "drives": [
  {
   "id": "xxxx",
   "name": "Example Drive"
  },
  {
   "id": "xxxy",
   "name": "Another Example Drive"
  },
  // ...
```

As you can see, the fields I don't need have been removed, but the fields I wanted to opt into have not be added. I wondered if I had just got something wrong in regards to the fact that `capabilities` is itself an object, but trying it with another simple property (`hidden`) also yields no luck.

What else do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Drive API v3 does not support this.

However, the Google Drive API v2 does! You can try it out [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/drives/list?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22items(id%2Cname%2Ccapabilities)%22%7D).

If you are not able to use v2 instead of v3, you will have to do what [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) suggested and fetch all the IDs of the drives, then get each one to retrieve the fields you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Fields * should return all of the fields available for any response

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I cant test this i dont have access to any shared drives.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#driveList",
 "drives": [
 ]
}
```

If you try doing a drive get on each drive again with fields=* you may get some additional information about the drive that way.

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/get
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, it does. But I don't seem to be able to tread the middle ground of having some of the non-default options but not all of them.

Comment: Thats all there is then.  If fields * doent return it then your not going to be able to see it.   Try doing a get on each drive see if you get some more information.

Comment: What I mean is that using `*` does give me all the fields (including the ones I want which I don't get by default), which is good. But in doing that, I'm also getting a whole load of information I don't want. Multiplied across all users' requests,  that's a waste of bandwidth. The scenario I'm going for is to get _some_ extra fields but not all of them. That's my struggle.

Comment: * is the sign for all you will be returning all the fields.  You can then verify that the data you actually need is in fact there.  You can then use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.drives.get to test your fields to only return the ones you need.

Comment: Yes, that part is all fine and I had tried all that prior to asking the question. The problem is when I do the last step - using the API explorer to ask for the specific fields I require - it does not return the fields I'm asking for.